# Adding input fields and setting their ids dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, append, dynamic-forms

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function getData1() {
    var innerhtml1 = $('.load1').html();
    $('.main_div').append(innerhtml1);
  }
  getData1();

  $(document).on('click', '.add_question', function() {
    let lengthQstn = $('.main_div').children().length;
    let questionHtml = $('.load1').html();
    let appendQstn = questionHtml.replace(/0/g, lengthQstn).replace(/add_question/g, "remove_question").replace(/add question/g, "remove question");
    $('.main_div').append(appendQstn);
  })

  $(document).on('click', '.add_option', function() {
    var dataParent = $(this).attr('data-parent');
    let lengthOpt = $("#option_" + dataParent).children().length;
    lengthOpt++;
    var dataParent = $(this).attr('data-parent');
    let optionHtml = $('.load2').html();
    let appendOpt = optionHtml.replace(/count/g, lengthOpt).replace(/0/g, dataParent);
    $("#option_" + dataParent).append(appendOpt);
  })

  $(document).on('click', '.remove_question', function() {
    var dataParent = $(this).attr('data-parent');
    $("#question_" + dataParent).remove();
  })

  $(document).on('click', '.remove_option', function() {
    var dataParent = $(this).attr('data-parent');
    var dataIndex = $(this).attr('data-id');
    $("#row_" + dataParent + '_' + dataIndex).remove();
  })
})
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}

.remove_option,
.remove_question {
  background-color: rgb(204, 177, 177);
}

.add_question,
.add_option {
  background-color: rgb(201, 233, 222);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.2.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <center>
    <h2>New Form</h2>
  </center>
  <div class="main_div">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="load1 hide">
  <div class="parent_div mb-5 mt-5" id="question_0">
    <div class="div1">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">
          <label id="question_0">Question_0</label>
          <input type="text" name="question_0" id="question_0" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="col-3">
          <button id="add_question_0" class="form-control add_question mt-4" data-parent="0">add_question</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="div2" id="option_0">
      <div class="row" id="row_0_1">
        <div class="col-6">
          <label id="option_0_1">option_0_1</label>
          <input type="text" name="option_0_1" id="option_0_1" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="col-3">
          <button id="add_option_0" class="form-control add_option mt-4" data-parent="0">add
                            option</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row" id="row_0_2">
        <div class="col-6">
          <label id="option_0_2">option_0_2</label>
          <input type="text" name="option_0_2" id="option_0_2" class="form-control">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="load2 hide">
  <div class="row" id="row_0_count">
    <div class="col-6 option_0_count">
      <label id="option_0_count">option_0_count</label>
      <input type="text" name="option_0_count" id="option_0_count" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="col-3">
      <button id="remove_option_count" class="form-control remove_option mt-4" data-parent="0" data-id="count">remove option</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have made a page for dynamically appending input fields for new questions, as well as new options.

All are input fields only, I have to generate an index for the fields.

But, when I click on `"add option"` the options input fields are appending but the index is not being generated correctly; also I have to generate an index similarly for the buttons too. Please help with this part.

Also, I have to dynamically remove the added option fields too when clicked on "remove option" button, I have commented it as of now.

Comment: I spent a while watching your code and there are few things to say before addressing the question. You are starting from a question (question+its own options) already existing in dom and at page ready you are populating its captions and ids. Plus you have one button to add an option to that question or to add new question from scratch with its own options. Now said that I could see you create the new questions from an hidden element instead of using templates. Plus you change id using fake ids on html that you replace with js...

Comment: there's some mess with that approach.. and you also have duplicated it here and there that you shouldn't. The point is that I made so many modifications that I can't even remember how was the original. I'm using template content elements with no ids upfront that I just clone and populate their caption/ids before adding to the dom. But it went too far and maybe it's no more the answer you were expecting. So I'm asking: are you available to a huge refactor that does more or less the same? or you are strictly asking why your code doesn't work?

Comment: yes i can use a refactor

Comment: Unfortunately I trashed anything I came out with .. if your comments arrived earlier probably I would have something to post as answer.

Comment: okay thanks i figured it out, but i have another query,  "$(this).parent().parent().parent().remove();"  how can i access the element i have to remove without using parent() method but by using id, also i have updated the code above

Comment: you can of course use `document.getElementById` without using any relative reference point since id are unique in the whole document.

Comment: but then i'll have to write multiple functions for multiple generated buttons because ids for these buttons are also dynamically made

Comment: it was the main issue in your code that I addressed in my second comment but I did a mistyping: _"there's some mess with that approach.. and you also have duplicated ***IDs*** here and there that you **shouldn't**."_ In short your id can't be duplicated or you'll break the id strategy entirely. It's invalid html. Use classes instead! and use `event.target` on your handlers to know which element fired the event. To get an element having a class in its ancestors line, use: `event.target.closest('.parentclass')`

Comment: `$(this)` will work as `event.target` as long as it's inside a function defined as `function(){}` and not with the arrow operator like `()=>{}`

Comment: i didn't get that? :/ i have to re-write "$(this).parent().parent().parent().remove();" can you provide a refactor for the same

Comment: for question: `$(this).closest('.parent_div').remove();` for option: `$(this).closest('.row').remove();`

Comment: that works fine, thanks, so basically i can also use event.target at the place of $(this) and it will work the same

Comment: not exactly .. it requires some awareness on what's going on. A function that will be called by the event, will be passed a value as first argument being the `Event` object. So to see that value inside your event handler you should define it as `.on('click', function(event){ console.log(event.target); })` . There are some shades related to `event.target`, `event.currentTarget` and event delegation. If you are interested you can find everything on mdn about it

Comment: thank you will read about it there, also i have again updated my code its now working like i wanted.

Comment: "*i have again updated my code its now working like i wanted.*" - congratulations! If this has solved your problem, please revert the code in your question back to its initial state, and post the working code (in which your problem is solved) as an answer to the question; that way you can accept your own answer (which is perfectly valid, and encouraged) though you have to wait a couple of days to do so; and others can learn from you.

Comment: alright i'll see how i can do that, thanks.